# jQuery Validation - require field only if another field is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery validation-select required if checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573487/jquery-validation-select-required-if-checkbox-checked)

I'm validating a form with jQuery Validation. I'm trying to come up with a rule that will  validate fields as required if a field in a particular set of fields is filled:

```
<form id="donate-form">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" required="required" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="address1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="address2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="city" /><br />
    <select name="state">
        <option value="">- State -</option>
        <option value="va">Virginia</option>
        <option value="md">Maryland</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="text" name="zip" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

All address fields are optional unless someone fills out address1, city, state, *or* zip, then they should all be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kDHF/1/)

Using `depends`, fill in your requirements.

```
var depends = function() {
    var vals = '';
    $('form > *').not(':eq(0)').each(function () {
        vals += $(this).val();
    });

    return vals.length > 0;
};
```

You should change the selectors to something more specific to fit your needs. ie not `$('form')`