# Validation of a minimum of two input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-validate

I'm looking to make an input validation. Basically, I have a form with 5 text field but the first two should have a condition: At least one of the two must be completed.

Currently the validation I use jQuery validate, but that does not fulfill this function, would you have any idea?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please post your code and your attempt so far.

Comment: post your code, how far were you be able to do it.

Comment: This is a job for 'required if' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573487/jquery-validation-select-required-if-checkbox-checked

Comment: Hi guys, my code is very simple .. 5 input and plugin jquery validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote OP:

> *"At least one of the two must be completed. 
>
>
>   Currently the validation I use jQuery validate, but that does not
>   fulfill this function, would you have any idea?"*

Incorrect... it **does** have this ability.  See documentation:  [http://jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

It's called the `require_from_group` method included in the [`additional-methods.js`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) file.  Usage as follows:

1) Give each item in the group a common `class`.

**HTML**:

```
<input class="productinfo" name="partnumber">
<input class="productinfo" name="description">
```

2) Define the rule as follows, where the first parameter is the minimum number required from the group and the second is the `class` you created above.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            partnumber:  {
                require_from_group: [1,'.productinfo']
            },
            description: {
                require_from_group: [1,'.productinfo']
            }
        },
        groups: {
            mygroup:  "partnumber description"
        }
    });

});
```

Now, at least `partnumber` OR `description` must be filled out.

3)  Optionally, to clean up the duplication of error messages, use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) as follows, which will lump the error messages for the two inputs above into one.

```
groups: {
    mygroup:  "partnumber description"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the person has moved to third field(use **onfocus** to determine this), you can validate it.Check if one of the two fields is filled.If not report it and focus on the first field.

Comment: Hi, Yes i think it's just a provided in JS, but i don't know how i can to make it work, actualy i test with this : <pre>if(input.value != null || input2.value != null)</pre> but no result :(

Comment: Why don't you post your code on jsfiddle, so I can help better?