# Drop-down box dependent on the option selected in another drop-down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have 2 different SELECT OPTION in a form.

The first one is Source, the second one is Status. I would like to have different OPTIONS in my Status drop-down list depending on the OPTION selected in my Source drop-down.

Source:

```
<select id="source" name="source">
     <option>MANUAL</option>
     <option>ONLINE</option>
</select>
```

Status:

```
<select id="status" name="status">

</select>
```

Options:
- If Source is MANUAL, then Status is OPEN or DELIVERED
- If Source is ONLINE, then Status is OPEN or DELIVERED or SHIPPED

My non-working attempt:

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var option = document.getElementById("status").options;
            if (document.getElementById('source').value == "MANUAL") {
                $("#status").append('<option>OPEN</option>');
                $("#status").append('<option>DELIVERED</option>');
                }
            if (document.getElementById('source').value == "ONLINE") {
                $("#status").append('<option>OPEN</option>');
                $("#status").append('<option>DELIVERED</option>');
                $("#status").append('<option>SHIPPED</option>');
                }
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573487/jquery-validation-select-required-if-checkbox-checked

Comment: I have a problem bit near to ** $("#status").append('<option>OPEN</option>'); ** assume that I have to append selected options to my multiple Dropdown:

`
$("#status").append('<option value="1">one</option>');
$("#status").append('<option value="2">two</option>');
$("#status").append('<option value="3">three</option>');
`
So I want my Dropdown be selected already no need to select again manualy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this...  [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQBFZ/1)

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Source: -->
<select id="source" name="source">
     <option>MANUAL</option>
     <option>ONLINE</option>
</select>

<!-- Status: -->
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option>OPEN</option>
    <option>DELIVERED</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).on('ready', function () {

    $("#source").on('change', function () {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val() === "ONLINE") {
            $("#status").append("<option>SHIPPED</option>");
        } else if (el.val() === "MANUAL") {
            $("#status option:last-child").remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 12):

I am posting this answer because in this way you will never need any plugin like jQuery and any other, This has the solution by simple javascript.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "manual" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("OPEN","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("DELIVERED","delivered");
            break;
        case "online" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("OPEN","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("DELIVERED","delivered");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("SHIPPED","shipped");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
    <body>
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Source:
        <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select source</option>
        <option value="manual">MANUAL</option>
        <option value="online">ONLINE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Status:
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="status" id="status"><option value="">Select status</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <select id="status" name="status">
            <option value="open">OPEN</option>
            <option value="delivered">DELIVERED</option>
        </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more details, I mean to make dynamic and more dependency please take a look at my article  [create dynamic drop-down list](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/create-dynamic-drop-down-list/)

Answer (score 2):

In [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/XH6vh/embedded/result,js,html,css/) you'll find a solution I deviced. The idea is to have a selector pair in html and use (plain) javascript to filter the options in the dependent selector, based on the selected option of the first. For example:

```
<select id="continents">
 <option value = 0>All</option>   
 <option value = 1>Asia</option>
 <option value = 2>Europe</option>
 <option value = 3>Africa</option>
</select> 
<select id="selectcountries"></select>
```

Uses (in the jsFiddle)

```
 MAIN.createRelatedSelector
     ( document.querySelector('#continents')           // from select element
      ,document.querySelector('#selectcountries')      // to select element
      ,{                                               // values object 
        Asia: ['China','Japan','North Korea',
               'South Korea','India','Malaysia',
               'Uzbekistan'],
        Europe: ['France','Belgium','Spain','Netherlands','Sweden','Germany'],
        Africa: ['Mali','Namibia','Botswana','Zimbabwe','Burkina Faso','Burundi']
      }
      ,function(a,b){return a>b ? 1 : a<b ? -1 : 0;}   // sort method
 );
```

[**Edit 2021**] or use data-attributes, something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("change", checkSelect);

function checkSelect(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;

  if (origin.dataset.dependentSelector) {
    const selectedOptFrom = origin.querySelector("option:checked")
      .dataset.dependentOpt || "n/a";
    const addRemove = optData => (optData || "") === selectedOptFrom 
      ? "add" : "remove";
    document.querySelectorAll(`${origin.dataset.dependentSelector} option`)
      .forEach( opt => 
        opt.classList[addRemove(opt.dataset.fromDependent)]("display") );
  }
}
```

```css
[data-from-dependent] {
  display: none;
}

[data-from-dependent].display {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<select id="source" name="source" data-dependent-selector="#status">
  <option>MANUAL</option>
  <option data-dependent-opt="ONLINE">ONLINE</option>
  <option data-dependent-opt="UNKNOWN">UNKNOWN</option>
</select>

<select id="status" name="status">
  <option>OPEN</option>
  <option>DELIVERED</option>
  <option data-from-dependent="ONLINE">SHIPPED</option>
  <option data-from-dependent="UNKNOWN">SHOULD SELECT</option>
  <option data-from-dependent="UNKNOWN">MAYBE IN TRANSIT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Almost what I want, but how to add `<option>All</option>` under selectcountries?

Answer (score 2):

```
    function dropdownlist(listindex)
    {
         document.getElementById("ddlCity").options.length = 0;
         switch (listindex) 
         {
             case "Karnataka":
                     document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[0] = new Option("--select--", "");
                     document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[1] = new Option("Dharawad", "Dharawad");
                     document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[2] = new Option("Haveri", "Haveri");
                     document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[3] = new Option("Belgum", "Belgum");
                     document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[4] = new Option("Bijapur", "Bijapur");

                 break;

             case "Tamilnadu":
                 document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[0] = new Option("--select--", "");
                 document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[1] = new Option("dgdf", "dgdf");
                 document.getElementById("ddlCity").options[2] = new Option("gffd", "gffd");


                 break;
         }

    }
```

*
                    State:
                
                    --Select--
                    Karnataka
                    Tamilnadu
                    Andra pradesh
                    Telngana

```
    <div>
        <p>

            <label id="lblCt">
            <span class="red">*</span>
                City:</label>
            <select id="ddlCity">
               <!-- <option>--Select--</option>
                <option value="1">Dharawad</option>
                <option value="2">Belgum</option>
                <option value="3">Bagalkot</option>
                <option value="4">Haveri</option>
                <option>Hydrabadh</option>
                <option>Vijat vada</option>-->
            </select>
            <label id="lblCity"></label>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: please give some details

Answer (score 0):

You're better off making two `selects` and showing one while hiding the other.

It's easier, and adding `options` to `selects` with your method will not work in IE8 (if you care).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help or solve your problem or you think not that understandable visit http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/.

HTML DYNAMIC DEPENDENT SELECT

```
<div class="frmDronpDown">
<div class="row">
    <label>Country:</label><br/>
    <select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $country) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>State:</label><br/>
    <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

GETTING STATES VIA AJAX

```
<script> function getState(val) { $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_state.php",
data:'country_id='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#state-list").html(data);
}
});} </script>
```

READ STATE DATABASE USING PHP

```
<?php require_once("dbcontroller.php"); $db_handle = new DBController();if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])) {
$query ="SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query); ?> <option value="">Select State</option><?php foreach($results as $state) { ?> <option value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?></option><?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this, I have noticed that it far better to show and hide the  tags instead of adding and removing them for the DOM. It performs better that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be updated to replace the defunct functions `.change` & `.ready`

```
$(document).on('ready',function()  {

    $("#source").on('change', function(){
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val() === "ONLINE") {
            $("#status").append("<option>SHIPPED</option>");
        } else if (el.val() === "MANUAL") {
            $("#status option:last-child").remove();
        }
    });

});
```