# Dynamically Populating Dropdown list based on previous selection

Tags: php, mysqli

I have gone through some of the suggested solution to this issue, but none seems to give me what I wanted. I want a simplest way of populating three dropdown list , in which selection 1 determines the output of dropdown 2, which invariably determines the output of dropdown list 3. Pls, I  need a simple php way of achieving this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop-down box dependent on the option selected in another drop-down box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728666/drop-down-box-dependent-on-the-option-selected-in-another-drop-down-box)

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes more sense to do this with ajax and JavaScript...

**The usual process goes:**

*User selects first item...*
Page requests matching second drop-down options from server, and adds them to the <select> using JavaScript.

*User selects a second item...*
Page requests matching third drop-down options from the server. Populates <select> via JavaScript.

Otherwise you will have to send the entire form incomplete to the server and refresh the entire page for each step until it's done. You could write a php-only way to do this, but unless you have a very specific requirement, you will be dragging down the average speed of the internet for no good reason.

Comment: http://daveismyname.com/demos/autocomplete/ is also handy... obviously you are using the info to populate the next box inline etc.

Comment: I am yet to get a suitable solution to the above. If anyone has a simple ones that can fit into the above question, it will be appreciated

Comment: You are kind of asking someone to do your job for you... you could always put it up on ODesk and ask someone to solve it for money.