# Make drop down list dependent on another drop down in MVC Core

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

This is similar to the question asked [Drop-down box dependent on the option selected in another drop-down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728666/drop-down-box-dependent-on-the-option-selected-in-another-drop-down-box) except I would like to use a C# class to keep a list of the drop down values rather than pure html. The jQuery used in the previous question does not work with what I am trying to do.

I want a user to select a vehicle Make and then have the model List be dependent on what Make was selected

C# Class: DropDowns.cs

```
public static List<SelectListItem> MakeList (string defaultLabel = "---"){

    List<SelectListItem> makeList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    makeList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="defaultLabel", Value = ""});
    makeList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Ford", Value = "Ford"});
    makeList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Toyota", Value = "Toyota"});

    return makeList;}

public static List<SelectListItem> ModelList (string defaultLabel = "---"){

    List<SelectListItem> modelList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    modelList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="defaultLabel", Value = ""});

    //Ford models
    modelList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="F-150", Value = "F-150"});
    modelList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Mustang", Value = "Mustang"});

    //Toyota models
    modelList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Rav4", Value = "Rav4"});
    modelList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text="Tundra", Value = "Tundra"});

    return modelList;}
```

HTML: myView.cshtml

```
<select name="make" asp-for="Make" asp-items="DropDowns.MakeList()"></select>
<select name="model" asp-for="Model" asp-items="DropDowns.ModelList()"></select>
```

I'm not really sure if it is possible to use a jQuery for asp-items. Maybe I would need to add if statements in my modelList?

Comment: Whilst you could make the second drop down appropriately populated based on a default selection on page render, any subsequent change is going to require some JavaScript to run to update the contents of the dropdown based on any other selections as your server-side code will no longer be running and it's all being evaluated at the client. Either you've going to have to render all the combinations client-side and have the JS update it appropriately, or have the first selection call back from the JS using AJAX or similar to get the options for that selection and update the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asp-items` relies on the server to parse, if the drop-down list is dynamically changed in this way, the client and the server need to maintain real-time interaction. So this method is impossible. You need to use jQuery.

When you see the page, `asp-items` have been parsed into html. At this time, html can be changed through jQuery.

```
<select name="make" asp-for="Make" asp-items="DropDowns.MakeList()"></select>
<select name="model" asp-for="Model" asp-items="DropDowns.ModelList()"></select>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        let model = $('#Model').children()
        $('#Make').change(function () {
            let make = $(this).val()
            if (make == 'Ford') {
                $('#Model').empty()
                $('#Model').append(model)
                $('#Model option').eq(4).remove()
                $('#Model option').eq(3).remove()
            } else if (make == 'Toyota') {
                $('#Model').empty()
                $('#Model').append(model)
                $('#Model option').eq(2).remove()
                $('#Model option').eq(1).remove()
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```